# Dangers of reading data from a large JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, performance, react-native

I have a JSON file with about 30,000 keys. What are the dangers of importing the JSON as an object and reading directly from it?

I'm using React Native, thus I would import it to the component's file and read from it as needed.

Comment: The only danger, if you do not `eval()` any parts or something like that, would be extended loading-times.

Comment: Iterating over a 30k keys json isn't a hard job for any computer. What matters is what you are doing with the information. If you are creating DOM based on this data, you may have slowness. Remember to do all your long processes in a async way.

Comment: There is no danger, what danger was you thinking about.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: The JSON police will come knocking at your door. That's as dangerous as I can make it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading this large JSON dataset in the browser, it could be worth to load it using a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), so that the loading part would be handled not only in a asynchronous way, but even in a separate Thread. What you need to do is to create a `worker.js` file that will be imported in your main js file, for instance, let's look at this Web Worker, that loads a file in background:

```
// (main.js, your main application file)
var fileworker = new Worker('worker.js');
    fileworker.onmessage = function(e) {
        var datasetsList=e.data;
        whendone(datasetsList);
    };
    fileworker.onerror = function(e) {
      console.error('ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message);
    };
    var readFileAsync = function() {
      fileworker.postMessage(fileupload.files);
    }
```

As you can see the Worker will read the file as soon as is fired

```
  fileupload.addEventListener('change', readFileAsync);
```

At this point the execution happens in a separate Thread, leaving the main thread (hence the UI thread as well) free to update the interface without pain.

The Web Worker will do the background job, and fire back the results, like in this example, where I'm loading a large dataset and applying some transformations as well

```
// (worker.js, the worker file)
var readFiles = function (files,whendone) {
    var count = files.length;
    var datasetsList = [];
    var readFile = function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReaderSync();
        var result=reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        var parsedData = d3.csvParse(result);
            parsedData.forEach(function (row) {
                parsedData.columns.forEach(function (column) {
                    if (!row[column]) {
                        delete row[column];
                    }
                    var coercedNum = +row[column];
                    if (!isNaN(coercedNum)) {
                        row[column] = coercedNum;
                    }
                });
            });
            datasetsList.push({ data: parsedData, name: file.name });
            if (!--count) {
                whendone(datasetsList);
            }

    };

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        readFile(files[i]);
    }
}
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    var files = e.data;
    readFiles(files, function (datasetsList) { // done
        postMessage(datasetsList);
    });
}, false);
```

Code snippet taken from [PAIR-code/facets](https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets/blob/gh-pages/worker.js)

So your dir structure will be at least like

```
root/
 index.html
 css/
 js/
  |-index.js
  |-worker.js
```

Comment: This is a really good answer but I'm not sure its applicable to this question. It is for react-native.

Comment: Thanks, this is true, I think also that could be applied to react-native as well as methodology, but I'm not sure how is applicabile. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-workers and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10269